# Sort datatable from a comma delimited list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to find a way to do a custom sorting over a datatable.

I have a comma delimited string list like "John,Jake,Joe,Julie" and my actual records in datatable are sorted as : Jake,Joe,John,Julie

How can I change the datatable sort according to my list ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide the code?

Comment: You want the DataTable row indexes to match the order in which the names appear in the list?  I'm not sure that is sorting, more like reordering.  Either way, it seems like a simple search and swap algorithm.

Comment: can you show the code that you are using currently this would help out a lot in regards to others seeing how you are currently retrieving the data to be use against the datatable also the simplest way to do this would be to  alter the `Select Statement and do an OrderBy that Column Name`

Comment: If your name are stored in a `List<T>` you could sort on a `List<T>` if you were not aware

Comment: What RDBMS (SQL Server, MySQL) are you using if any?

Comment: Do you really need a datatable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is homework, so I'm going to describe an algorithm and let you implement it ;-)

For each name in your comma separated list

- Select rows from your source table where the name is equal to the current name from your list
- Union/append the results to the results already received on previous iterations (eg into a new table/recordset/array)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the DataTable, you could do LINQ to CSV. See [this](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-CSV-using-DynamicObject) and [this](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-CSV-using-DynamicObject-and-TextFieldParser).